# How to Debug/Monitor SMTP Communications?

Tags: debugging, smtp, monitoring

Debug HTTP is easy, you have all sort of tools to do it (like Fiddler). What about SMTP?

**How to Debug SMTP Communications?**

My target system is Windows.

---

Suggested tools:

- Ethereal
- tcpdump
- Microsoft Network Monitor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Ethereal - its a free network protocol analyzer.

The SMTP protocol is all ascii, so once you see whats inside the TCP connection, you should be good to go.

It will take a bit of work learning how to use Ethereal.

Comment: In this case, I prefer "Microsoft Network Monitor". It is very easy to use... But I was looking to something more specific to SMTP.

Comment: FWIW, a few years ago, Ethereal was renamed WireShark: http://www.wireshark.org/  BTW, WireShark is subject to U.S. export regulations [http://www.wireshark.org/download.html ==> http://www.wireshark.org/export.html]

Answer (score 11):

For the two people who responded with Ethereal: We renamed the project to Wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org) back in 2006 due to trademark issues. I strongly recommend upgrading.

Depending on your exact issue, Wireshark's [Follow TCP Stream](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvFollowTCPSection.html) feature is pretty useful for debugging Internet Message protocols, including SMTP.

Answer (score 11):

How to capture emails with Wireshark:

1. [Get wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html)  -> Install
2. Into filter enter `smtp` click <kbd>Apply</kbd>
   [image]
3. When you get filtered lines click right mouse button on one of them and select 'Follow TCP stream'.
   You should get window like following
   [image]
4. (OPTIONAL) If you want to inspect contents of email that are base64 encoded
   Copy part that looks like gibberish into one of base64 to text converters, [there are plenty online.](https://www.base64decode.org/) You should get readable text that was sent.

[image]

Hope this saves you some time.

Answer (score 6):

[smtp-cli](http://smtp-cli.logix.cz/) is good for this. From the homepage:

> smtp-cli is a powerful SMTP command line client with a support
>   for advanced features, such as STARTTLS, SMTP-AUTH, or IPv6

In addition to being a full-featured client, its `--verbose` option makes it
the tool I think you're looking for to track down SMTP issues (like, for instance,
why a server is rejecting a given to: address, which is how I found the tool :-) )

Again from the homepage:

> It's also a convenient tool for testing and debugging SMTP servers' setups.
>   Even the hardcore mail admins used to typing the SMTP protocol over telnet
>   need a specialised tool when it comes to verifying encryption settings of
>   their TLS enabled server with a subsequent user authentication. Such things
>   are pretty hard to type into a telnet session by hand :-)

Comment: +1 though not a monitoring tool, it works excellent when trying to talk to fresh SMTP servers and see why things go wrong. Very easy to setup some test scripts to fire towards an SMTP server to see if it is configured correctly, or if your client-side is configured correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a SMTP development server, like [Neptune](http://donovanbrown.com/post/2008/10/20/Neptune.aspx) or [Antix](http://www.antix.co.uk/Projects/SMTPServerForDevelopers.aspx). Both work the same way: they create a "fake" SMTP server in your machine so you can test your e-mail sending methods, without actually sending the messages they receive.

Comment: +1; though Windows only, they work well. Antix has a new version which is very very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Use tools like **ethereal** (www.ethereal.com) or **tcpdump** (www.tcpdump.org), if you want to see the SMTP traffic.

If you like to check your server for compliance with relaying standards, do a

```
telnet relay-test.mail-abuse.org
```

from your SMTP server and it checks your server for relaying vulnerabilities.