# How To Trace Win32 Socket Calls and Requests

Tags: winapi, sockets, trace, monitor

How can I effectively trace the raw data sent to my socket server listening on a win32 machine? I want the trace to be specific to the port my server is listening on, so I can monitor only that traffic.

I want to see how the data exchange works on the wire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

[Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f&displaylang=en)
or
[Ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/)
or
[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

They all come with rich filtering capabilities so filtering on a single port / address or protocol should be quite easy.

Related:

- [Free Network Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302/free-network-monitor)
- [How to Debug/Monitor SMTP Communications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883163/how-to-debug-monitor-smtp-communications)

Answer (score 1):

ETW can do it. ETW is built in to windows you don't need external tools. Here is [blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/netmon/archive/2009/05/13/event-tracing-for-windows-and-network-monitor.aspx) on that from technet.